# How to find file with range parameter?

Tags: linux, grep

For the following files:

```
res1, res2, res3, 1res4, res100
```

Expected *result* would be `res1, res2  and res3`. How to use 'grep' to get this result.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: grep doesn't find files by *name*, it searches through their *contents*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep is not needed.

```
ls res[1-5]
```

If you want to have number range try:

```
ls res{1..100}
```

Comment: If i need to grab from first 100 directories it doesn't work :(

Comment: That's because character classes don't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly what was requested:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep '^\./res[1-5]$'
```

will ignore res100, and only look for *files* in the current directory.

To get sorted output (as "ls" would do), add that step:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep '^\./res[1-5]$' |sort
```

Comment: The "find" command's options limit it to the current directory, and only files.  The grep does the pattern-matching requested (globbing cannot do this).

Comment: This doesn't print anything

Comment: Sorry - typed from memory - the "./" in the output isn't filtered:  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep '^\./res[1-5]$'

Comment: By the way, "find" doesn't sort - I'll add an example